# Android LiveData is always null in instrumented test

Tags: android

In my app, I have a ViewModel looks like that:

```
public class MyExampleViewModel {

   private LiveData<MyEntity> myLiveData;

   @Inject
   MyRepository myRepository;

   @Inject
   public MyExampleViewModel() {
   }

   public void init(final Long id) {
      if (this.myLiveData == null) {
         this.myLiveData = myRepository.getById(id);
      }
   }

   public void toggleStar() NullPointerException {
      final MyEntity myValue = this.myLiveData.getValue();
      myValue.setStar(!myValue.getStar());
      myRepository.save(myValue);
   }
}
```

Also the code of `MyRepository#getById` (myDao is a room DAO and it is injected):

```
    public LiveData<MyEntity> getById(final Long id) {
        return myDao.getById(id);
    }
```

The code of `MyDao#getById`:

```
    @Query(
            "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=:id"
    )
    LiveData<MyEntity> getById(final Long id);
```

I also try to test this ViewModel using

```
myExampleViewModel.init(myId);
myExampleViewModel.toggleStar();
```

but after the `init` call my LiveData value is always null.

My first question is: is it a best practice to use `getValue()` on my LiveData or should I use `Transformation.map`?

My second question is: in my test, how can I have a LiveData populated? I tried to use `CountingTaskExecutorRule` and `InstantTaskExecutorRule` but without any success.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post the code of the `getById` method from the `MyRepository` class?

Comment: @LucaPizzini yes sure, I edited my post with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood why `myLiveData` is not populated in my test. According to the documentation "LiveData objects that are lazily calculated on demand." and `LiveData#getValue` only get the value if the LiveData is already populated but doesn't calculate the value.

So I fixed my test adding a getter on my LiveData and an observer on my LiveData to force the calculation like that `LiveDataUtil.getValue(myExampleViewModel.getMyLiveData());` with `LiveDataUtil#getValue`:

```
public class LiveDataUtil {

    public static <T> T getValue(final LiveData<T> liveData) throws InterruptedException {
        final Object[] data = new Object[1];
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Observer<T> observer = new Observer<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable T o) {
                data[0] = o;
                latch.countDown();
                liveData.removeObserver(this);
            }
        };
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> liveData.observeForever(observer));
        latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //noinspection unchecked
        return (T) data[0];
    }
}
```

After this fix, `MyExampleViewModel` class looks like:

```
public class MyExampleViewModel {

   private LiveData<MyEntity> myLiveData;

   @Inject
   MyRepository myRepository;

   @Inject
   public MyExampleViewModel() {
   }

   public void init(final Long id) {
      if (this.myLiveData == null) {
         this.myLiveData = myRepository.getById(id);
      }
   }

   public void toggleStar() NullPointerException {
      final MyEntity myValue = this.myLiveData.getValue();
      myValue.setStar(!myValue.getStar());
      myRepository.save(myValue);
   }

   public LiveData<MyEntity> getMyLiveData() {
       return myLiveData;
   }
}
```

And my test method:

```
myExampleViewModel.init(myId);
LiveDataUtil.getValue(myExampleViewModel.getMyLiveData());
myExampleViewModel.toggleStar();
```

I fixed my test but I still don't know if using `LiveData.getValue` is a best practice and I found few documentation on this topic. So, I'm interested in this topic if you have more information.